# Specify different environment variable's values for different AWS Lambda function versions in CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have AWS CloudFormation template for Lambda function which contains function's configuration and configuration of two function's versions, something like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31"

Description: Lambda function configuration

Resources:
  EndpointLambda:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
      FunctionName: "endpoint-endpoint"
      Handler: "com.test.aws.RequestHandler::handleRequest"
      Runtime: java8
      Code:
        S3Bucket: "lambda-functions"
        S3Key: "test-endpoint-lambda-0.0.1.jar"
      Description: Test Lambda function
      MemorySize: 256
      Timeout: 60
      Environment:
        Variables:
          VAR1: "test value 1"
          VAR2: "test value 2"

  LambdaFunctionVersion1:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Version"
    Properties:
      FunctionName:
        Ref: "EndpointLambda"
      Description: "version 1"

  LambdaFunctionVersion2:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Version"
    Properties:
      FunctionName:
        Ref: "EndpointLambda"
      Description: "version 2"
```

How can I specify different values for environment variables `VAR1` and `VAR2` for `LambdaFunctionVersion1` and `LambdaFunctionVersion2`?

Comment: Short answer is use a map that relates to the version I’m AFK right now but will post an answer shortly! Check this out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html

Comment: Thanks for the direction for next investigations! I'll be glad if you extend your comment to the wide answer

Comment: Yep will do nearly home!